# Error: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting this error when I try to populate users First_Name in a csv file. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong

```
 import csv

# Define users 
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    users =raw_input('Number of users: ')
    try:
        users = range(0,int(users))
        valid_input = True
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        pass

First_Name = ["Test"+str(user) for user in  range (1, users+1)]
Last_Name = ["User%s" %user for user in users]
Email_Addresses = []
for user in users:
    email= raw_input("Email domain for user %d: " %user)
    Email_Addresses.append(Last_Name[user] + email)
Password = ["Password1" for user in users]
Group =["Test" for user in users]
Admin = ["Yes" for user in users]
# open a file for writing.
# open a file for writing.
with open('users.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    writer.writerows(zip(Email_Addresses, Password, First_Name, Last_Name, Group, Admin))
```

This is the Traceback I am getting
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       First_Name = ["Test"+str(user) for user in  range (1, users+1)]
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: You need to include the *full* traceback, so we don't have to guess where your error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

`users` is a list:

```
users = range(0,int(users))
```

but you then try to create a *new* range from that list:

```
First_Name = ["Test"+str(user) for user in  range (1, users+1)]
```

where `users + 1` is an attempt to add `1` to a list.

Don't do that. Just loop over your existing range:

```
First_Name = ["Test"+str(user + 1) for user in users]
```

Comment: With that script I will be forced to enter the email domain over and over again depending on number of users i have given in my input. I need it to populate all the users with the one given email address.